# Which release to use on toll free bridged data types?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-foundation

I have doubt and need some suggestion on following code,

```
NSArray*  onscreenwindows = (NSArray*)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
```

Which one of the following release is right?

```
if(onscreenwindows)
{

...

[onscreenwindows release];
}
```

OR

```
if(onscreenwindows)
{

...

CFArrayRef cfonscreenwindow = (CFArrayRef)onscreenwindows
CFRelease(cfonscreenwindow);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are toll-free bridged you can use both, as you like.

Comment: Although the `if` statement is not optional in the latter case, since `CFRelease` will crash if you pass it `NULL`, whereas sending any message—including `release`—to `nil` will simply do nothing.